# How to calculate the difference between two data in the same list column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula, calculated-column

I want to know how to calculate the difference between two data in the same column of a list. It is useful if we are monitoring the changes (daily-monthly-etc).
[image: Question]

TX for your suggestions on how to make a calculated column with such desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Calculated column does not support the way you want. For options you can check, workflow or Power Automate are tools you may use. If you are using SharePoint On-Premise, you can turn to SharePoint Designer Workflow. For SharePoint Online users, I will suggest using Power Automate.

Comment: tx Jerry! I do not know how to use Power Automate to do this task. Could you please explain how to do it?